# Regex for a specific word that contain parentheses, how can I escape the parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I building a function that will check a string and add paragraph and bold tags if the word at the begining of the string matches any word in list of words.

I've based it roughly on a bad word filter I found on Stackoverflow and its working great except for words that contain parentheses and I can't work out how to escape them!

So in the below example "Item one", "Item two", "Item three" all match.
But "item (four)" fails.

How can I escape the parentheses in the word array so the regex still works?

```
//array of words to match 

$words= array("Item one", "Item two", "Item three", "item (four)");




//strings that should match

 $string = "item (four)"  //fails    
 $string = "item one"   //works




//loop through array of word and if a match is found add p and b tags

for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++) {         
        if (preg_match('/^' . $words[$i] . '(:|\b)/i', $string ) === 1) {          
            $stringInput =   preg_replace("/^" . $words[$i] . "(:|\b)/i", "<p><b>" . ucwords(strtolower($words[$i])) . " </b></p>", $string );
        } 
    }
```

`

I've tried to escape the parentheses in the array and I've tried split the word in the array to add the delimiter that way

Comment: "escape the parentheses" - this is the correct answer. Please show how you have tried it, and how it failed to work.

Comment: Why using complicated regex functions, and not basic functions like [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), [stripos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php), [str_starts_with()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php) or any other?

Comment: I think you need https://3v4l.org/sTOcp. Please try, and let know via a comment if it is what you want, I will then post as an answer.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I think I got so caught up in using regex I didn't think to use anything else!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes that seems to have done it, I don't know why I didn't think of preg_quote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
<?php

$words= array("Item one", "Item two", "Item three", "item (four)");

$string = "item (four)";  //fails    
//$string = "item one";   //works

//loop through array of word and if a match is found add p and b tags
$stringInput = $string;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++) {         
    $stringInput = preg_replace("/(?!\B\w)" . preg_quote($words[$i], "/") . "(?!\B\w)/i", "<p><b>" . ucwords(strtolower($words[$i])) . " </b></p>", $stringInput );
}
echo $stringInput . PHP_EOL;
```

See the [demo online](https://3v4l.org/sTOcp).

**NOTES**:

- `$stringInput = $string;` must be used since the `$string` value is going to be modified in a loop
- `(?!\B\w)`s are adaptive word boundaries that only require a word boundary if the adjoining character on the right/left is a word char
- `preg_quote($words[$i], "/")` escapes the chars inside the `$words`.

Answer (score 0):

To escape regex strings you need to use [`preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) function.

```php
<?php
$words = ["Item one", "Item two", "Item three", "item (four)"];

$string = "item (four)";
// $string = "item one";

foreach ($words as $word) {
  $replacement = '<p><b>' . ucwords(strtolower($word)) . '</b></p>';
  $pattern = '/^' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '(:|\b)/i';
  $stringInput = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}
```